# Deploying a Streamlit Application via Google Cloud Platform with a Machine Learning Model continuously runs/connects

Tags: python, docker, google-cloud-platform, streamlit, google-artifact-registry

I created a Machine Learning Prediction tool with Streamlit and want to deploy to Google Cloud Platform (GCP) so the tool can be accessed via a domain. However the tool, when loaded via Google Cloud Run, is constantly 'Connecting'[Connecting symbol in Streamlit App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXw38.png) or 'Running' [Running symbol in Streamlit App](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H3qzc.png). This happens to the point where information required to be entered for the prediction to take place, cannot be entered

Initially I thought this was an issue with the caching so I introduced [streamlit's caching features](https://docs.streamlit.io/library/advanced-features/caching) to no help. The following steps are used to deploy the streamlit app:

1. Docker Image built (Locally, files accessed via GitHub)
   1.1 At this point the tool works perfectly when a local container is created
2. Docker Image pushed to a GCP Artifact Registry Repo
3. Image deployed via GCP Cloud Run

Comment: Make sure you're using streamlit > v1.18.  Can you please share developer tools console logs and version of streamlit you're using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's a memory issue related to GCP. Make sure you're allocating more memory than the default